# Algoritmo matematico que me retorna nan y inf

Tags: c++, algoritmos, matemáticas

Estoy intentando hacer una función de seno, mediante las series de Taylor.
Este algoritmo funciona en Java y python sin embargo en c++ me produce errores ya que al calcular con n términos grandes el numero se convierte en nan o inf.

Este es el algoritmo en C++

```
#include<iostream>
#include<math.h>
#include<iomanip>
#include<string>
#include<cmath>
#include<limits.h>

using namespace std;

#define Math_PI 3.14159265358979323846

class Math{
    public: 
        int factorial(int n){
            int factor = 1;
            for(int i=n;i>0;i--){
                factor*=i;
            }
            return factor;
        }
        float radianes(float d){
            return (d*Math_PI)/180;
        }

        double sen(double x){
            double seno = 0;
            int sentido = 1;
            for(int i=1;i<100;i+=2){
                seno+=sentido*(pow(x,i)/factorial(i));
                sentido*=-1;
            }

            return round(seno);
        }
};

int main(){
    
    Math calcu;
    float degrees;
    cout<<"Digita el angulo: ";cin>>degrees;

    degrees = calcu.radianes(degrees);

    cout<<"El angulo en radianes es: "<<degrees<<endl;
    cout<<"El seno del angulo es: "<<roundf(sin(degrees))<<endl;
    cout<<"El seno del angulo es: ";
    cout<<calcu.sen(degrees);
   return 0;
}
```

Este es el mismo algoritmo y procedimiento en python, sin embargo en este no genera error alguno en el calculo

```
import math

def factorial(n):
    factor = 1
    for i in range(1,n+1):
        factor*=i
    return factor

def sen(degree):
    seno = 0
    sentido = 1
    i = 1
    while(i<100):
        seno+=sentido*(pow(degree ,i)/factorial(i))
        i+=2
        sentido*=-1
    seno = round(seno)
    return seno
def cos(degree):
    coseno = 0
    sentido = 1
    i = 0
    while(i<100):
        coseno+=sentido*(pow(degree, i)/factorial(i))
        i+=2
        sentido*=-1
    coseno = round(coseno)
    return coseno

def euler(exp):
    e = 1
    i = 1
    for i in range(101):
        e+=pow(5, i)/factorial(i)
        
    e = round(e)
    return e

def main():
    numero = float(input("Digita un angulo: "))
    degree = (numero*math.pi)/180  
    print(f'El seno de {degree} es : {sen(degree)}')
    print(f'El coseno de {degree} es: {cos(degree)}')
    
    exponente_euler = int(input("Digita el exponente de e: "))
    print(f'El resultado de elevar e^{exponente_euler} es: {euler(exponente_euler)}')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Al ejecutar el codigo en C++ obtengo esta salida:

```
Digita el angulo: 90
El angulo en radianes es: 1.5708
El seno del angulo es: 1
El seno del angulo es: nan
```

Y quisiera saber como puedo reducir la longitud del double seno, ya que en cierto punto del buble for se elevan demasiado los decimales y se transforma en inf, y posteriormente en un nan.

Comment: Aparentemente es un problema de precisión que hace que tengas una división por 0. Baja el número de iteraciones de 100 a 10 y verás que funciona bien. Dos cosas más: `round` redondea al número entero más cercano y la clase `Math` es innecesaria ya que no guarda ningún estado, solo la usas para contener las funciones. Si lo que querías es "agrupar" de alguna manera las funciones, puedes ponerlas en un namespace.

Comment: El problema es que al reducir el bucle For a 10 los primeros ángulos funcionan bien como sin(90)=sin(1.57π) y retorna 1 y para 180 retorna un 0, pero para 270 retorna cantidades incoherentes y de igual manera para 360 cuando debería oscilar entre 0-1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

La función `factorial` usa el tipo `int` para calcular el resultado. El tipo `int` es un tipo de dato entero de 32 bits con signo, por lo que el valor más alto que puede almacenar es `2.147.483.647`

Atendiendo a tu función `factorial`:

```
int factorial(int n){
    int factor = 1;
    for(int i=n;i>0;i--){
        factor*=i;
    }
    return factor;
}
```

Vemos que `factor` es la variable donde se almacena dicho factorial. Así, si tenemos en cuenta los resultados de los factoriales:

```
12! =   479.001.600
13! = 6.227.020.800
```

Pues vemos que `n` no puede ser mayor de 12 o el programa no será capaz de realizar el cálculo... sin embargo luego nos encontramos con este otro código:

```
for(int i=1;i<100;i+=2){
    seno+=sentido*(pow(x,i)/factorial(i));
    sentido*=-1;
}
```

En el que vemos que `factorial` puede recibir hasta el valor 99, muy por encima del máximo que hemos comentado antes.

Podrías pensar que quizás sería buena idea usar un tipo de dato que acepte valores más grandes. Tienes a tu disposición `long long`, 64 bits, pero en este caso establecerías el límite en `22!`, lo cual sigue sin ser suficiente.

Como solución puedes optar por hacer los cálculos sobre un `std::string`. La parte mala de esta solución es que te toca implementar las operaciones matemáticas a mano.

Otra solución pasa por usar clases pensadas para manejar números realmente grandes, como por ejemplo el tipo `cpp_int` de la librería boost

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/multiprecision/cpp_int.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace boost::multiprecision;

cpp_int factorial(int n){
    int factor = 1;
    for(int i=n;i>0;i--){
        factor*=i;
    }
    return factor;
}

int main(){
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    cout << fact(n) << '\n';
}
```

Por otro lado, para manejar decimales estás usando el tipo `float`. Este tipo tiene una precisión máxima de 6 dígitos. Si tras esto detectas problemas de precisión, prueba a cambiar a `double`. Este otro tipo te ofrece 12 dígitos de precisión.

Comment: Solucione el error cambiando el tipo de dato de la función factorial por long double, lo cual me dió mayor presicion en el factorial evitando la indeterminación y haciendo que pueda obtener resultados tan precisos cómo la función que viene por defecto en el lenguaje. Gracias por la ayuda

Comment: @LuisFernandoNúñez los tipos en coma flotante poseen una precisión relativa. En el caso de `long double`, el estándar indica que debe poseer, al menos, la misma precisión que `double`, y deja en manos del compilador el darte más precisión. Asumiendo que fuesen el doble de bytes para este tipo, te estaría dando una precisión de unos 25 dígitos. Con esta precisión es complicado que pueda calcularte el factorial de 100 correctamente. Sin embargo, si sirve para tus propósitos, perfecto